# How do I add another method?

Tags: c#, http

I have two classes, I want to add a method to MyWebRequest class. In this method I have to time the HTTP request I am making.
Please help me with this. 
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace HTTP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
            string filename = "RequestLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            MyWebRequest request = new MyWebRequest();
                            request.Request();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is MyWebRequest.cs and this is where I want to do all of my http requests and time how long it took to retrieve the response.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace HTTP
{
    class MyWebRequest
    {
        public void Request()
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("lstWebSites");
                request.Method = "GET";

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                    Console.Write("Errorcode: {0}", (int)response.StatusCode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Status);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void NewMethod(){}` right above `public void Request()` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need a new method. You can use the `Stopwatch` class to time how long it takes to run your method. If you need to access it from a different method, then just save it in a variable and return it from a second method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes I'll try stopwatch, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about stopwatch?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            MyWebRequest request = new MyWebRequest();
            stopwatch.Start();
            request.Request();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapse: {0}", stopwatch.Elapse);
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally got my code to run, thanks for the help. But I don't understand why some websites are bringing back 2 request results and some are giving me 3 request results?